# LoadException: Root value already specified on custom control

Tags: java, javafx-8, fxml, fxmlloader

Example below causes

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: Root value already specified.
```

The code is written according to example here: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/custom_control.htm

Code:

```
public class NavigationView extends ButtonBar {

   private static final String defaultTemplate = "/fxml/navigator.fxml";

   public NavigationView() {
      this(null);
   }


   public NavigationView(URL resource) {
      //FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("custom_control.fxml"));

      if( resource == null ) {
         resource = getClass().getResource(defaultTemplate);
      }

      FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(resource);
      fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
      fxmlLoader.setController(this);

      try {
         fxmlLoader.load();
      } catch (IOException exception) {
         throw new RuntimeException(exception);
      }
   }

   public static class Runner extends Application {
      @Override
      public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
         Scene scene = new Scene(new NavigationView(), 800, 600);
         primaryStage.setTitle("NavigationView");
         primaryStage.setScene(scene);
         primaryStage.show();
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
         Runner.launch(args);
      }
   }
}
```

If I remove line

```
fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
```

then the view is empty, which is essential, because remains no connection between `NavigationView` and FXML template.

How to accomplish?

**UPDATE**

`FXML` is follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar?>

<ButtonBar maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="38.0" prefWidth="651.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.91">
  <buttons>
    <Button fx:id="previousButton" mnemonicParsing="false" text="&lt;&lt; Previous" />
      <Button fx:id="nextButton" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Next &gt;&gt;" />
      <Button fx:id="editButton" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit" />
      <Button fx:id="createButton" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Create" />
      <Button fx:id="saveButton" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Save" />
      <Button fx:id="cancelButton" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Cancel" />
      <Button fx:id="deleteButton" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
  </buttons>
</ButtonBar>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a ["dynamic root"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#root_elements). The `<ButtonBar>` element is an instruction to the `FXMLLoader` to create an object from the `ButtonBar` class, and (since it's the root element of the FMXL file) use it as the root of the structure created. If you want to call `setRoot(this)`, you already have an object created that is going to play that role.

So you should use:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar?>

<fx:root type="ButtonBar" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="38.0" prefWidth="651.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.91">
  <buttons>
    <Button fx:id="previousButton" mnemonicParsing="false" text="&lt;&lt; Previous" />
      <Button fx:id="nextButton" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Next &gt;&gt;" />
      <Button fx:id="editButton" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit" />
      <Button fx:id="createButton" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Create" />
      <Button fx:id="saveButton" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Save" />
      <Button fx:id="cancelButton" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Cancel" />
      <Button fx:id="deleteButton" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
  </buttons>
</fx:root>
```

Comment: But what if I wish to use `<ButtonBar>`? I found workaround by creating extra container outside FXML. Are there any other ways?

Comment: This does create a button bar, because the object you are setting as root is a ButtonBar instance: NavigationView extends ButtonBar.

Comment: I guess the question is, if you use `<ButtonBar>` *and* create a subclass of `ButtonBar`, you have two button bars. Why do you want two of them?